# Apex Oracle How To Create Conditional Column

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex, apex-code, oracle-apex-5

I am new to using Apex Oracle to create a table and insert values in it. I need to create a column that is only mandatory if the value for another column is "Y" (if it is "N", then it is not mandatory). The type of the other column is a CHAR with length 1. How could I do this? Would this be done in SQL Scripts or SQL Commands? Similarly, is there a way to delete old SQL commands that were used (that now I realize are incorrect)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Oracle APEX and Stack Overflow. You can create objects (tables/views) in both SQL commands and SQL Scripts. For ad hoc creating, SQL Commands is probably easier. To remove (called "drop" in oracle) objects that you create, that can be done in SQL Commands,  or even easier in the "Object Browser" - locate the object and select "drop". Note that this cannot be undone.

About the requirement for a column to be conditionally mandatory:
This can be enforced in the database using a check constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  id     NUMBER GENERATED AS IDENTITY,
  col1  VARCHAR2(1),
  col2  VARCHAR2(10));


Table TEST_TABLE created.

ALTER TABLE test_table ADD CONSTRAINT test_table_c1 
  CHECK ((col1 = 'Y' AND col2 IS NOT NULL) or (col1 != 'Y'));

Table TEST_TABLE altered.

INSERT INTO test_table(col1,col2) VALUES ('N',NULL);

1 row inserted.

INSERT INTO test_table(col1,col2) VALUES ('Y',NULL);

INSERT INTO test_table(col1,col2) VALUES ('Y',NULL)
Error report -
ORA-02290: check constraint (SAMPLEAPPS.TEST_TABLE_C1) violated

INSERT INTO test_table(col1,col2) VALUES ('Y','Some Value');

1 row inserted.
```